# Input sound volume grow itself

Tags: sound, settings

My microphone input volume grow with no reasons. I manually set it to Unamplified, and it goes up till like 10-20% and there starts to be so loud and make some noises on voice calls. Is there a fix?

Can I force it to keep the Unamplified volume?